# how the values gets passed in this nested function example

Tags: javascript

Learning Javascript from here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

I understand these points

1. You can nest a function within a function
2. The inner function can be accessed only from statements in the outer
   function. [ The nested (inner) function is private to its containing
   (outer) function. It also forms a closure ]
3. The inner function forms a closure: The inner function can use the
   arguments and variables of the outer function, while the outer
   function cannot use the arguments and variables of the inner
   function.

However I couldn't understand how the second value actually goes in all the way to the inner function as-if it was passed as a parameter to inner function?

```
function outside(y) {
    console.log('y is ' + y);

    function inside(x) {
        console.log('x is ' + x);
        return x+y;
    }

    return inside;
}

var a = outside(3);
//console.log(a);  // this is easy to understand

/* output:

y is 3
ƒ inside(x) {
     console.log('x is ' + x);
     return x+y;
 }
*/

var b = a(2); // Not able to clearly understand how 2 is interpreted as parameter to nested function.
              // Is this bcoz a function was returned earlier and now we passed 2 to that function??
console.log(b); 

/*  output
y is 3
x is 2
5
*/

console.log('--------------');
var c = outside(3)(2); // How is 3 passed as outer function paramter and 2 passed as inner function parameter?
console.log('---------');
console.log(c);

/* output
y is 3
x is 2
5
--------------
y is 3
x is 2
---------
5
*/
```

EDIT-1:

Thanks a lot all who helped, understood the concepts and wrote this which works as expected.

```
function outside(y) {
    console.log('y is ' + y);
    function inside(x) {
        console.log('x is ' + x);
        function innermost(z) {
            console.log('z is ' + z);
            return x+y+z;
        }
        return innermost;
    }
    return inside;
}
outside(3)(2)(1);

/* output
y is 3
x is 2
z is 1
6
*/
```

EDIT-2:

Another way of writing the function to meet the above objective mentioned in EDIT-1.

```
function A(x) {
  function B(y) {
    function C(z) {
      console.log(x + y + z);
    }
    C(3);
  }
  B(2);
}
A(1); // logs 6 (1 + 2 + 3)
```

In this example, C accesses B's y and A's x. This can be done because:

1. B forms a closure including A, i.e. B can access A's arguments and
   variables.
2. C forms a closure including B.
3. Because B's closure includes A, C's closure includes A, C can access
   both B and A's arguments and variables. In other words, C chains the
   scopes of B and A in that order.

The reverse, however, is not true.

- A cannot access C, because A cannot access any argument or variable
  of B, which C is a variable of. Thus, C remains private to only B.

Comment: From `arguments` to currying... you are learning fast...

Comment: "*Is this bcoz a function was returned earlier and now we passed 2 to that function??*" - yes, exactly that. You can even try calling `a` multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `outside(someValue)` call is a `function`. So to call the result (inner) function you need to call `outside` function twice. One time to get the inner function `outside(3)` and once again to call it `outside(3)(4)`.

```
let innerFunc = outside(3) // here you get the inside function as result
innerFunc(4) // call it
```

Wich is the same as:

```
outside(3)(4)
```

Some more info:

```
outside(3) // this calls the outside function and returns the inside function
outside(3)(4) // this calls the outside function returns the inside
//function as result of first call and calls the inside function with (4)
```

Comment: thanks , however, i am having difficulty in exactly here understanding that these two are same, how is this becoming same? what is this function calling syntax - outside(3)(4). Coming from a Java 1.6 background, it's hard to really understand the concept

Comment: hmm, thanks for edit +1, so basically outside()() refers to calling the same function twice.. because calling once just return another fn

Comment: Yes `outside(3)` results a function and you just call that function with one more call `(4)`

Comment: @spiderman no it does not call "the same function twice", it calls a function which returns another one that is then called.

Comment: But the second call is for the inner function, not same function twice!

Comment: thanks for pitching in @Jonas W. , understood its calling one after the other and not the same. so, may be this statement of Nikola might not be completely correct 'you need to call outside function twice', what he meant is as per his  further explanation. I will try writing two nested functions and calling thrice, this is interesting

Answer (score -1):

A lot like this, I'd assume.

```
function outside(y) {
    console.log('y is ' + y);
    function inside(x) {
        console.log('x is ' + x);
        function inide(z) {
            console.log('z is ' + z);
            return y+z;
        }
        return x+y, inide;
    }
    return inside;
}
outside(3)(2)(1);
```

Comment: What should this be??

Comment: seems he meant writing two nested function and calling thrice, to do sum of three number relating to my example.. `function outside(y) {
    console.log('y is ' + y);
    function inside(x) {
        console.log('x is ' + x);
        function innermost(z) {
            console.log('z is ' + z);
            return x+y+z;
        }
        return innermost;
    }
    return inside;
}
outside(3)(2)(1);

/* output
y is 3
x is 2
z is 1
6
*/`

Comment: Please edit your answer to add more information. You should be providing the asker with information, not the other way around!

Comment: I didn't ask him a question, he's just a cool spiderman guy and i told him some code. hes a spiderman so he's cool and program good. he understands u can chill tf out homie. thanks for the advice tho god bless ur heart and god bless america